# Setting "template" instances as same class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Imagine you have a `Vector2()` class and you want to prepare some ready-made instances such as `Vector2.NORTH = Vector2(0, -1)`. Now setting them directly as class attributes is, unfortunately, not possible (python throws NameError since the class is not defined yet). Example below:

```py
class Vector2:
    # throws NameError: cannot do it directly
    NORTH = Vector2(0, -1)
```

What are best practices to obtain a class equivalent to the above?
(i.e. supporting the syntax `Vector2.NORTH`)

What I discovered so far:

- built-in `@classmethod` decorator returning the instance (requires the ugly `Vector2.NORTH()`)
- custom `@classproperty` decorator (arguably the best solution? but... additional boiler-plate and a bit too verbose (e.g. cannot exploit local namespace shorthands, especially relevant if you have a lot of nested definitions, copies of constants on demand?))
- overloading `__getattr__` (this seems messy, since we would have to somehow store these constants inside the method although we could maybe store only the init args outside and retrieve them just before the init)
- inherit from the `__metaclass__` type?? (not sure about this one... wouldn't we need to define these constants (i.e. `NORTH`) using the metaclass `__init__` and not using the `__init__` of the class we are defining?)
- dynamically alter the class in-place after the definition (downside: not robust against `from ... import Vector2` since the config is not executed, although we could overcome this with some kind of  `classinit()` classmethod and a flag to only run it the first time `__init__` gets called.)

I apologize for the overkill. I am aware this is mostly perfectionism nonsense with fancy OOP sauce, but as you can tell I became a bit too obsessed with it now. Why isn't there a more straight-forward and elegant way to achieve this? What's the standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way is to use [metaclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/), for example:

```
class Vector2Meta(type):
  def __init__(cls, *args):
    cls.NORTH = cls(0, -1)


class Vector2(metaclass=Vector2Meta):
  x = None
  y = None

  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"Vector2({self.x}, {self.y})"


print(Vector2.NORTH)
```

output:

```
Vector2(0, -1)
```